# Cannot pause the audio when turning off the screen on the mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, audio

I've tried various native listener with `<audio>` element on mobile device with control panel. However, Turning off the screen after playing the audio, the audio wouldn't pause but i saw m.youtube can do that. So, how could i pause the audio when turned screen off?

```
<audio controls loop id="a"> 
    <!-- <source src="MerryChristmas.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> -->
    HTML5 audio not supported
</audio>

var audio = document.getElementById('a')
var source = document.createElement('source')
source.type='audio/mpeg'
source.src='./MerryChristmas.mp3'
audio.appendChild(source);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the visibilitychange event. I haven't test it, so I'm not sure if it will work, but the [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) seem like it should

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  audio.pause();
});
```

EDIT: Changed to document.addEvent... from window.addEvent...

Comment: thank you for your reply. It works on android but ios.

Comment: try using window.addEventListener('webkitvisibilitychange', ...). might need to use both for each platform

Comment: I changed `window.addEventListener` to `document.addEventListener`. It seems working on safari too now.